# pandas explode dataframe by values of cell

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I from a dataframe:

```
df = C1 C2 C3 from_time to_time
     a   b c     1         3
     q   t y     4         9
```

I want to explode it by the value of from_time , to_time, so it will be:

```
df = C1 C2 C3 time from_time to_time
     a   b c    1      1         3
     a   b c    2      1         3
     a   b c    3      1         3
     q   t y    4      4         9
     q   t y    5      4         9

...
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with `range`s if small DataFrames:

```
df.insert(3, 'time', df.apply(lambda x: range(x.from_time, x.to_time + 1), axis=1))
df = df.explode('time')
print (df)
  C1 C2 C3 time  from_time  to_time
0  a  b  c    1          1        3
0  a  b  c    2          1        3
0  a  b  c    3          1        3
1  q  t  y    4          4        9
1  q  t  y    5          4        9
1  q  t  y    6          4        9
1  q  t  y    7          4        9
1  q  t  y    8          4        9
1  q  t  y    9          4        9
```

For better performance use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and for new column use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per index values with `from_time` values:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.to_time.sub(df.from_time) + 1)]
df.insert(3, 'time', df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(df['from_time']))
print (df)
  C1 C2 C3  time  from_time  to_time
0  a  b  c     1          1        3
0  a  b  c     2          1        3
0  a  b  c     3          1        3
1  q  t  y     4          4        9
1  q  t  y     5          4        9
1  q  t  y     6          4        9
1  q  t  y     7          4        9
1  q  t  y     8          4        9
1  q  t  y     9          4        9
```